# Always fit whole screen with PIXI.js renderer

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

Pixie is a 2D graphics framework based on WebGL with canvas fallback. I created Pixie renderer and I'd like to fill whole screen with the renderer. Currently, I create some fixed size renderer:

```
function GameRenderer(width, height) {
  this.renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(
                        this.width=width,
                        this.height=height,
                        {backgroundColor : 0x000000}
  );
}
```

So I'd like to resize **pixel size** of the rendering area to that of the current browser screen area. This must also work on mobile devices. How to do this without somehow interfering with pixi.js and breaking it?

By **pixel size** I mean pixel width and height of the render area. This means if the browser inner area has 1000x600 pixels I want to fill it with 1000x600 pixels large image.

Comment: Do you want to scale the area to fit the screen, or expand the area to fill the screen while keeping all objects at their original size? If you want scaling, do you want to keep the ratio?

Comment: Well with canvases, we know two things, **pixel size** (amount of pixels on the image data) and **css size** (which can be set by stuff like `width: 100%`). I was hoping that using bold text on pixel size is obvious enough.